# Intersections of Two Circles and Tangent Lines Problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

I need to write a solution for this problem, but I'm completely stumped on how to do this.

Comment: The triangle is very likely to be a peculiar one, because the tangency condition in $Q$ and the collineation of $APB$ cannot be imposed imultaneously in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Do you know that $AP\cdot AB=AQ^2$? What is $AQ^2+BQ^2$? That should get you started.

Comment: Oh....... AQ^2 + BQ^2 = AB^2, so the answer is 12*16*1/2=96. Thank you, I knew there was some tangent property I was forgetting!

Comment: @Mark. Please elaborate a bit. The 2 tangents to the Circles do not automatically  imply Angle AQB = 90° . Find the drawing a bit too suggestive. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Use $AP\cdot AB=AQ^2$ and $BP\cdot BA=BQ^2$ (this is a standard property of tangent/secant). Add them to get $AQ^2+BQ^2=AB^2$ which tells you two things - that the angle at $Q$ is a right-angle, and that $AQ$ and $BQ$ are diameters (they are perpendicular to the respective tangents).

Comment: @Mark.Thanks, ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\measuredangle A=\alpha$ and $\measuredangle B=\beta$.

Thus, $\measuredangle PQB=\alpha$ and $\measuredangle AQP=\beta$, which gives
$$2(\alpha+\beta)=180^{\circ}$$ or
$$\alpha+\beta=90^{\circ}$$ or
$$\measuredangle AQB=90^{\circ}.$$

Thus, $AQ=6$ and $BQ=8$ and we get
$$S_{\Delta AQB}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot6\cdot8=24.$$

Comment: How did you get that ∡PQB=α and  ∡AQP=β?

Comment: @Wiifan This is a theorem about the angle between a tangent and a chord.